# Very simple nested file iteration does not behave as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was writing a python script to parse 2 text files, find if content of second text in some line is the same as the first one and in case, swap it with another variable.

The issue arises trying to do a `for` loop with the files, for example the following code:

```
ase = open('text1.txt','r')
endurance = open('text2.txt','r')

for x in ase:
 print('sheet')
 for y in endurance:
    print('yayyeeeeet')
```

Giving for example that text1 has 100 lines and text2, too,
the output should be:

```
sheet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet x100
```

Then starting with `sheet` again and 100x `yayyeeeet` again for 100 loops,
but the output is different which is as follows:

```
sheet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
yayyeeeeet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
sheet
```

Which I simply can't understand the reason of
tested with both python 2.7 and python 3.8.

Comment: `endurance` is an iterator, and you consume it the first time.

Comment: Please add the content of the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over an opened file just once... So, I suggest using `readlines()` instead like so:

```
ase = open('test.txt','r').readlines()    #<--- add .readlines() here
endurance = open('text2.txt','r').readlines()  #<--- add .readlines()

for x in ase:
    print('sheet')
    for y in endurance:
        print('yayyeeeeet')
```

Also, it's a good practice to close any opened files. So, I really suggest using `with` statement.

Comment: It is not necessary to use readlines() on the first one `ase`: it is in the outer-loop and only used once. Agree with your 'with'-remark.

Comment: Thanks for your coment. But according to the OP, he/she needs to start with `sheet` again.

Answer (score -1):

Iterators don't automatically reset once you have consumed them. The simplest solution is to re-open the "inner" file each time.

```
with open('text1.txt','r') as ase:
    for x in ase:
        print('sheet')
        with open('text2.txt','r') as endurance:
            for y in endurance:
                print('yayyeeeeet')
```

This avoids the need to read the entire file into memory.

---

If you want to leave both files open, you can use the `seek` method to rest the second file to the beginning, but I don't think this is guaranteed to work in combination with an iterator. You can use explicit calls to `readline`, though.

```
with open('text1.txt') as ase, open('text2.txt') as endurance:
    for x in ase:
        print('sheet')
        endurance.seek(0)
        for y in iter(endurance.readline, ''):
            print('yayyeeeeet')
```

Comment: You have redundantly added with ase = open('text1.txt','r') as ase, it can be assigned once and still function. with open('text1.txt','r') as ase:

Comment: If it were fixed before I commented, technically I wouldn't have seen it. Yet again.

Comment: So you predicted the future and answered my question. 

Comment: Regardless, it's fixed now. I'm removing my comments on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

As Paul Hankin says: endurance is an iterator. You can use it only once.
Try this instead:

```
with open('text2.txt','r') as f:
    endurance = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Overtime, your code without closing a file will accumulate and crash the system. Please ensure you close the file.

Comment: Very true, I didn't went that far, but changed my answer.